# What is the maximum number of comparisons required to find a key in a binary tree having 191 nodes and whose height is equal to nine?

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I know that for a completely filled binary tree, the height of that tree is equal to `floor(log2(N))`, and that the maximum number of comparisons to find a given key is simply `h+1`, or `floor(log2(N)) + 1`.

This question appears in the review for our final, and I cannot recall how to find the answer. The possible answers given are `7, 8, 9, 10`. I am fairly certain the answer is either `9` or `10`, but I don't know, because I'm not sure if I should be calculating the answer based upon the number `512` (`2^9`), or `191`.

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Since the height is specified, that's undoubtedly the easiest way to work.

The maximum number of comparisons is the maximum number of non-leaf nodes you could traverse getting from the root to a leaf node. Depending on how he's defined the height (which, unfortunately, isn't universally agreed upon) that will be either the height or one less than the height.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very **unbalanced** binary tree, which have 6 nodes whose height is 5.

```
1
 \
  2
   \
    3
     \
      4
       \
        5
         \
          6
```

Suppose you want to find 6. You must need 6 comparisions. (6 = 5 + 1)

So in your case, you must need 10 comparisions (10 = 9 + 1). Number of nodes don't affect the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the binary tree is sorted and starting from the root node, you need to compare the key against the current node, and determine whether you should traverse left or right or return the current node if it matches or return failure if the branch you want to pick does not exist.

In the worst case, you need 9 comparisons to reach the leaf node. You still need to have one more comparison against the leaf node to see if the value matches. So you need 10 comparisons.

If it guarantees the key is part of the tree, you only need 9 comparisons. Otherwise it is 10.